# BeautifulSoup not getting entirety of extracted class

Tags: beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I am trying to extract data from craigslist using BeautifulSoup. As a preliminary test, I wrote the following:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, NavigableString

link = 'http://boston.craigslist.org/search/jjj/index100.html'
print link
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(link).read())
print soup
x=soup.body.find("div",class_="content")
print x
```

Upon printing soup, I can see the entire webpage. However, upon trying to find something more specific such as the class called "content", it prints None. I know that the class exists in the page source as I looked on my own browser, but for some reason, it is not finding it in the BeautifulSoup parsing. Any ideas?

Edit:
I also added in the following to see what would happen:

```
print soup.body.article
```

When I do so, it prints out some information between the article tags, but not all. Is it possible that when I am using the find function, it is somehow skipping some information? I'm really not sure why this is happening when it prints the whole thing for the general soup, but not when I try to find particulars within it.

Comment: the way you've created the url seems unnecessary to me. and i can not directly copy paste it in my browser. have you checked the page source like pressing ctrl+u (not firebug or developer tool)?

Comment: Edited to make the url whole. And yes, I have checked the page source directly, it shows everything.

Comment: your code works for me and x returns the tag for the particular url you provided. try [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) module and check again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `find` method on the `BeautifulSoup` instance (your `soup` variable) is not the same as the `find` method on a `Tag` (your `soup.body`).

This:

```
soup.body.find("div",class_="content")
```

is only searching through the direct children of the body tag.

If you call `find` on the `BeautifulSoup` instance, it does what you want and searches the whole document:

```
soup.find("div",class_="content")
```